# LINQ query to SQL Script

Tags: linq, sql

Is anyone heard of any tool writing LINQ queries and converting them to SQL queries?

I mostly need this because I am a .NET developer and I'm weak in this section of SQL queries where sometimes I need them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using [LINQPad](http://linqpad.com)? That lets you see the SQL generated when it runs the query - and of course it's easy to experiment with to get the LINQ query right to start with :)

Comment: it's worth noting that you'll  have to pay for Autocomplete in LINQPad, that's why I still use VS to test my LINQ

Comment: I think LINQPad would be great if i can se the generated SQL Query. Will try and get back to the thread. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you write your query against a linq-to-sql datacontext, you can get the query text out like this:

```
CustomDataContext dc = new CustomDataContext(); //your DataContext here.
IQueryable<Customer> customerQuery = GetQuery(dc); //your query constructed here.
Console.WriteLine(dc.GetCommand(customerQuery).CommandText);
```

Comment: This requires code inside every project, I need an external tool to test on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Use sql profiler to get the sql as it is executed against the sql database.